# PDF to Text extractor in nodejs without OS dependencies

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdftotext

Is there a way to extract text from PDFs in nodejs without any OS dependencies (like pdf2text, or xpdf on windows)? I wasn't able to find any 'native' pdf packages in nodejs. They always are a wrapper/util on top of an existing OS command.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked [PDF2Json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json/)? It is built on top of [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). Though it is not providing the text output as a single line but I believe you may just reconstruct the final text based on the generated [Json output](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json/blob/master/readme.md):

> 'Texts': an array of text blocks with position, actual text and styling informations:
>   'x' and 'y': relative coordinates for positioning
>   'clr': a color index in color dictionary, same 'clr' field as in 'Fill' object. If a color can be found in color dictionary, 'oc' field will be added to the field as 'original color" value.
>   'A': text alignment, including:
>   left
>   center
>   right
>   'R': an array of text run, each text run object has two main fields:
>   'T': actual text
>   'S': style index from style dictionary. More info about 'Style Dictionary' can be found at 'Dictionary Reference' section

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job. -Bart

Answer (score 12):

After some work, I finally got a reliable function for reading text from PDF using https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist

To get this to work, first npm install on the command line:

```
npm i pdfjs-dist
```

Then create a file with this code (I named the file "pdfExport.js" in this example):

```
const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist");

async function GetTextFromPDF(path) {
    let doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(path).promise;
    let page1 = await doc.getPage(1);
    let content = await page1.getTextContent();
    let strings = content.items.map(function(item) {
        return item.str;
    });
    return strings;
}
module.exports = { GetTextFromPDF }
```

Then it can simply be used in any other js file you have like so:

```
const pdfExport = require('./pdfExport');
pdfExport.GetTextFromPDF('./sample.pdf').then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Hello @Jack, for me ONLY your code is working to extract text from pdfjs in nwjs app. I have been trying from 1 week. Finally got it working. Thanks a ton for your answer.

Comment: Getting following error:

The browser/environment lacks native support for critical functionality used by the PDF.js library (e.g. `Path2D` and/or `ReadableStream`); please use a `legacy`-build instead.

Comment: Worked flowless bro,thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Thought I'd chime in here for anyone who came across this question in the future.
I had this problem and spent hours over literally all the PDF libraries on NPM. My requirements were that I needed to run it on AWS Lambda so could not depend on OS dependencies.

The code below is adapted from another stackoverflow answer (which I cannot currently find). The only difference being that we import the ES5 version which works with Node >= 12. If you just import pdfjs-dist there will be an error of "Readable Stream is not defined". Hope it helps!

```
import * as pdfjslib from 'pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js';

export default class Pdf {
  public static async getPageText(pdf: any, pageNo: number) {
    const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNo);
    const tokenizedText = await page.getTextContent();
    const pageText = tokenizedText.items.map((token: any) => token.str).join('');
    return pageText;
  }

  public static async getPDFText(source: any): Promise<string> {
    const pdf = await pdfjslib.getDocument(source).promise;
    const maxPages = pdf.numPages;
    const pageTextPromises = [];
    for (let pageNo = 1; pageNo <= maxPages; pageNo += 1) {
      pageTextPromises.push(Pdf.getPageText(pdf, pageNo));
    }
    const pageTexts = await Promise.all(pageTextPromises);
    return pageTexts.join(' ');
  }
}
```

Usage

```
const fileBuffer = fs.readFile('sample.pdf');
const pdfText = await Pdf.getPDFText(fileBuffer);
```

Comment: I'm also trying to get pdfjs running inside a lambda function. When I'm importing the library, I get the following error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot find module './pdf.worker.js' Have you encountered this and, probably, found a solution for this?

Comment: Any chance you have updated this code for your needs in the past couple years.  I have been using this solution and its ok, but I would love it if there was a solution as good as whatever is happening here: https://pdftotext.com/

Comment: As I checked pdtto ext.com, they don't process pdf on the cloud, it looks like a browser solution using pdf.js

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me using node 14.20.1 using `"pdf-parse": "^1.1.1"`

You can install it with:

`yarn add pdf-parse`

This is the main function which converts the PDF file to text.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');
const assert = require('assert');

const extractText = async (pathStr) => {
  assert (fs.existsSync(pathStr), `Path does not exist ${pathStr}`)
  const pdfFile = path.resolve(pathStr)
  const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pdfFile);
  const data = await pdf(dataBuffer)
  return data.text
}

module.exports = {
  extractText
}
```

Then you can use the function like this:

```
const { extractText } = require('../api/lighthouse/lib/pdfExtraction')

extractText('./data/CoreDeveloper-v5.1.4.pdf').then(t => console.log(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the proposed PDF2Json you can also use PDF.js directly (https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist). This has the advantage that you are not depending on modesty who owns PDF2Json and that he updates the PDF.js base.